# Linking OpenCV to Qt Creator

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv, qt-creator

I'm trying to use opencv 4 in QT creator,
I'm working on Mac
but I can't be able to link the library, I always have a error like on picture 2.

[image: My configuration PATH]

[image: what I add on .pro file]

please help me, I'm really hopeless.

Answer (score 4):

So, I have a solution here, I have install the OpenCV 4. 
In

> /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.2.0_1/lib/pkgconfig

I have a opencv4.pc not opencv.pc and the "opencv development package not found" error came from here.

[image: terminal output]

Edit your .pro file with

```
QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config
CONFIG  += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv4
```

note that it's opencv4.

after you have to configure the Build Environment in Qt Creator normally.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

First of all be sure you installed OpenCV correctly and working fine. You can check OpenCV exist or not by:

> pkg-config --modversion opencv

It depends how you installed OpenCV but linking OpenCV libraries and flags to Qt is simply like adding these two line to your `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv # depends on how you installed
LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

[This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIXnD-9uh1k) is also very helpful.